# Silverlight CustomValidation on a class

Tags: silverlight, validation, customvalidator

If I add CustomValidation on a class or a class property, how do I trigger that from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If triggering from a class then you use

Validator.ValidateObject(classNameToBeValidated, new ValidationContext(classNameToBeValidated,null,null);

If on a single property use Validator.ValidateProperty....